# Explicit Formula of Heat Equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-series, fourier-transform, heat-equation

> Find the explicit formula for $u:[0,\infty)\times \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ satisfying the heat equation with the following initial conditions:
>   \begin{align*}
> u_t&=u_{xx}    \mathrm{\ \ \ \ \ \ in\ (0,\infty)\times \mathbb{R}^n}\\
> u(t,0)&=0      \mathrm{\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ for\ any\ }t\geq 0\\
> u(0,x)&=f(x)   \mathrm{\ \ \ \ for\ any\ }x\in [0,\infty)
> \end{align*}
>   where $f(x):[0,\infty)\to \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous and bounded function satisfying $f(0)=0$

Note that this is an exercise right after learning the fundamental solution of the heat equation. So the very first thing I do is to write 
 $$u(t,x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi t}}\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(y)e^{-\frac{|y-x|^2}{4t}}dy$$
and substitute the additional condition $u(t,0)=0$ but clearly I cannot proceed after this.

Comment: It is a result in Evans that $\lim_{t\to 0^+}u(t,x) = f(x)$. So you should get that this limit equals $f(0)=0$. The proof is a $\epsilon$-$\delta$ computation.

Comment: But how could I use the condition $u(t,0)=0$?

Comment: Method of images